# Python: Aggregate 3 lists and sum respective fourth list elements

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Not sure if this was asked in here.

I have four lists (3 ordered and the fourth needn’t be) of same length and want to aggregate the 3 first lists then sum the respective elements in the fourth list.

To give an example:

```
L1= [1,1,2,3,4]
L2= [2,2,2,5,6]
L3= [3,3,3,7,8]
L4= [10,20,30,40,50]
```

The expected output is:

```
L1= [1,2,3,4,0]
L2= [2,2,5,6,0]
L3= [3,3,7,8,0]
L4= [30,30,40,50,0]
```

What it does is that it looks at the first 3 list and checks whether elements are redundant (in the example, since 1 is redundant, it will only check in L2 and L3 if there is an element (not necessarily 1) that is repeated, that’s why in the output L2 and L3 still have 2 and 3 resp. in the first two positions). Then it aggregates these redundant elements as in the outputs by summing the respective elements in the list L4.

Suppose you have 4 lists, you look at the first 3 lists. When a redundancy occurs in one of these 3 lists (in the example, for instance 1 occurs two times) you check in the other two lists whether any of their elements are repeated the exact same time starting the exact same position as in the first list. In this example, 1 is in position 0 of L1 and is repeated in position 1 ( 1 is repeated two times), you now check in L2 and L3 if, in position 0 and 1 their elements are identical (2 is repeated 3 times in L2 -> aggregate only the first two)

Elements should be repeated starting the same position (lists have the same length) and occur the same number of times. That's why in L2 and L3 the first two redundant elements are aggregated keeping only two 2s and two 3s in L2 and L3 resp. As for L4 we summed the first two elements because that's where the previous conditions have occurred. Since we aggregated the two redundancies in each of the 3 lists(first 1s in L1, first 2s in L2 and first 3s in L3)we would like to fill the rest of the lists with 0 at their end to keep the same length as the original lists (len =5 here).

I managed to solve this using dataframes and groupby/agg but I need something faster as i’m using it in real-time for some sensor capture high-frequency data.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import repeat

def main():

    L1= [1,1,2,3,4]
    L2= [2,2,2,5,6]
    L3= [3,3,3,7,8]
    L4= [10,20,30,40,50]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data={'L1':L1, 'L2':L2, 'L3':L3, 'L4':L4}
    df = df.groupby(['L1','L2','L3'], as_index=False, sort=False).agg({'L4':sum})

    L1new =df['L1'].tolist()
    L2new =df['L2'].tolist()
    L3new =df['L3'].tolist()
    L4new =df['L4'].tolist()

    # keep initial length
    L1new.extend(repeat(0.0,len(L1)-len(L1new))
    L2new.extend(repeat(0.0,len(L2)-len(L2new))
    L3new.extend(repeat(0.0,len(L3)-len(L3new))
    L4new.extend(repeat(0.0,len(L4)-len(L4new))
```

Does anybody have an idea how to improve this code ? I need something way faster. 
Please also note that I'm doing this for increasingly and decreasingly ordered lists separately which adds up more time. (only shared the code for the increasing case)

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Any time someone has a bunch of parallel lists that they want to operate on, it's often a good idea to unify the data in some fashion to simplify the coding logic and maybe speed up performance. Such unification is occuring in your use of a DataFrame. So your current solution strikes me as a good one. But when you say it's way too slow, have you figured out how much of that time cost is spent converting the information from (a) parallel lists to (b) unified data to (c) new paralell lists? My first instinct is to wonder whether you need the parallel lists at all. Why not abandon them?

Comment: Second question: how much faster do you need this to be? Some sense of where your code is currently at (speed-wise) and where you need it to be would be useful – do you need a 5% improvement or 100%, for example? And how big are the lists in your real use case -- ie, approximate number of elements.